# If $f(x)=a |\sin x| + b e^{|x|}+c|x|^3$ and if $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$, find the values of $a,b$ and $c$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, derivatives

> If $$f(x)=a |\sin x| + b e^{|x|}+c|x|^3$$ and if $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$, find the values of $a,b$ and $c$.

Please note that if a function is differentiable at a point , it is also continuous there.
 Please prove using $$\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=f(c)$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to c^-}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$

Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

The differentiability of $f$ in $x=0$ is equivalente to the existence, finiteness and equality of the following limits:
$$
  \lim_{h\to 0^-}
    \frac
    {a |\sin h|  +  be^{|h|}  +  c|h|^3  -  b}
    {h}
=
  \lim_{h\to 0^+}
    \frac
    {a |\sin h|  +  be^{|h|}  +  c|h|^3  -  b}
    {h}
$$
Let us compute each summand separately:

### 1

$$
\lim_{h\to 0^\pm}
  \frac{a|\sin h|}{h}
=
\pm
\lim_{h\to 0^+}
  \frac{a \sin h}{h}
=
\pm a
$$

### 2

$$
\lim_{h\to 0^\pm}
  \frac{be^{|h|}-b}{h}
=
\pm
\lim_{h\to 0^+}
  \frac{b(e^h-1)}{h}
=
\pm b
$$

### 3

$$
\lim_{h\to 0^\pm}
  \frac{c|h|^3}{h}
=
\pm
\lim_{h\to 0^+}
  c h^2
=
0
$$
Therefore the above equality turns into
$$
a+b = -a -b
$$
so $f$ is differentiable iff you choose
$$
a,b,c\in\mathbb R ~~\text{with}~~b = -a
$$

## Continuity

Concerning "differentiability implies continuity",
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \big\{f(x+h) - f(x)\big\}
~=~
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}h
~=~
\lim_{h\to 0} f'(x)h
~=~
0
$$
provided $f$ is differentiable at point $x$.